# How do I properly use a backslash to continue a line in an if statement?

Tags: python

e.g. D, if sum_p is not zero.

```
D = 1/sum_p if sum_p \
    else 0
```

What if I want to return the value? Should I do:

```
return 1/sum_p if sum_p \
else 0
```

or just write

```
if...
else: return 0
```

Comment: Remember to accept an answer to your question by clicking the check mark next to the one that solved your problem the best. You should do this for your old answered questions too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do a single statement conditional return, use:

```
return 1 / sum_p if sum_p else 0
```

This is **not an `if` statement**. It's a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). Think of it as

```
return (this_value if this_condition_is_true else that_value)
```

The `return` itself is *outside* the conditional.

If the line is long enough you have to split it up, stylistically I'd recommend using an ordinary `if` statement and two `return` statements.

In general, *don't use `\` as a line terminator*. [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) recommends you always use parenthesis:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation. Make sure to indent the continued line appropriately. The preferred place to break around a binary operator is after the operator, not before it. Some examples:

Comment: you have to do it the other way around, else 1/sum_p will fail when sum_p is 0. so it becomes return 0 if not sum_p else 1/sum_p

Comment: do i parenthesis the whole part after 'return?'

Comment: @ch3ka Try it. if `sum_p` is `0` then `if sum_p` is `False` and it will reach the `else` clause resulting in `0`.

Comment: @user1325302 Yes, if you want to wrap it over multiple lines. But you _shouldn't want to_. Only wrap lines that are too long, and in that case you should really break it up into multiple statements.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is fine if you're assigning it to a variable.

If you want to return the value, replace the assignment with a `return` statement.

Example:

```
return 1/sum_p if sum_p \
else 0
```

Comment: if sum_p return 1/sum_p else: return 0              like this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to stay away from escaping newlines. Quite often you can use parenthesis to accomplish the same goal.  There's too much potential for mistakes with escaped newlines as a space after the \ will probably break your code.  To use your example:

```
return (1.0 / sum_p if sum_p
    else 0)
```

Comment: what would u do if you want to return the value?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `\` unless absolutely necessary.

Use

```
D = 0 if not sum_p else 1.0/sum_p
```

Or

```
return 0 if not sum_p else 1.0/sum_p
```

If the lines get too long or complex, just use:

```
if cond: ...
else : ....
```

Comment: You don't need to invert the condition. It's not evaluated left-to-right, the condition is evaluated first, then only the appropriate expression.

Comment: This is of course correct, @agf. I don't know why, but I had the old trick in mind, where order matters for execution. Here: it does not.